# Displaying null data in choropleth using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, choropleth

I am working in ArcMap and I have created a choropleth map (using a "population" attribute) that is rendering things basically correct except that when the "population" attribute is null, representing no data, it does not render the associated polygon at all.

I would like the null data polygons to render white with a grey outline, as I have the polygons *with* data rendering with a shade of purple (depending on the "population" value as mentioned above) and a grey outline.

Is there a better way to go about it other than copying the layer and sticking it under the choropleth layer?

Comment: Well I ended up just creating a new layer from the selection of null data polygons, which works well although is perhaps not the most elegant solution. I am going to leave this as unanswered because it does not precisely answer the question of actually displaying the null data from the same layer the choropleth is built from.

Answer (score 2):

Run a field cal. on all null values and assign them a value of -9999.  You can then assign -9999 to 0 as a separate class and change the label to Null.

Comment: This, I assume, would indeed work but I ended up going with something a bit simpler, although perhaps clunkier.